# URL Rewriting on .NET

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting, bidirectional

How can I acheive bi direction rewriting to where the following occurs inbound to the web server

www.mysite.com/region/program/cat1/cat2/cat3

sends the request to the server

www.mysite.com/program.ASPX?idregion=(regionlookupnumber)&idcategory=3276

and when the server is going to write the above it converts it the other way.

Bi-directional URL rewriting on IIS7 using the URL rewriting package. We don't want to modify the source code if possible.

Any advise or resource or sample link please?

Answer (score 0):

I did this using the automatic friendly url template of the url rewriting package 2.0
It works really well. You just need to make sure to only re-write the urls you really need to. If you re-write img, link, etc. tags for instance, it can break your page.

Comment: The exact name of the template is "User-friendly URL"