# URL Rewriting on .NET (iis7)

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, url-rewriting

This is a task to build bi-directional URL rewriting on a .NET platform. The URL's are managed where the result should be.

`www.somewhere.com/Region/Program/Cat1/Cat2/Cat3/Catn/` for listings and

`www.somewhere.com/Region/Program/document-title-seperated-with-dashes-and-ending-in-a-real-44500012 document id.`

For Region it is a call to a database.

For Program it is a translation to a database.

For Cat1 - Catn it is a call to a database.

The current URL looks like
`www.somewhere.com/programname/?statictext&region=Number&cat=Number`

Comment: duplicate: [URL Rewriting on .NET](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5448478/102112)

Answer (score 1):

You can make your own RemapperPage class that implements IHttpHandlerFactory, or define rewriting rules in your .config file when you have installed http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite module.